# Exclusive use entity from a Product of Query

Tags: c#, linq, math

I have 3 lists that I am joining: `Product`s, `AcceptedOffer`s and `Delivery`s

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>() {
    new Product(){ Id = 1, Name = "Drink" }
};

List<AcceptedOffer> accepted = new List<AcceptedOffer>() {
    new AcceptedOffer(){ Id = 10, ProductId = 1  },
    new AcceptedOffer(){ Id = 11, ProductId = 1  }
};

List<Delivery> deliveries = new List<Delivery>() {
    new Delivery(){ Id = 101, ProductId = 1, Status = "Success" },
    new Delivery(){ Id = 102, ProductId = 1, Status = "Failure"}
};
```

I want to tie the deliveries back to the accepted offers but I can't find a way to query that has exclusive use of each AcceptedOffer/Delivery:

```
var test = from d in deliveries
           join p in products on d.ProductId equals p.Id
           join ao in accepted on p.Id equals ao.ProductId
           select new { d, p, ao };
```

This gives:

```
Drink | 10 | Success
Drink | 11 | Success
Drink | 10 | Failure
Drink | 11 | Failure
```

If I group by Accepted Offer, then `FirstOrDefault()` both deliveries succeeded; Group by Delivery and the first AcceptedOffer is the same..

I need:

```
Drink | 10 | Success
Drink | 11 | Failure
```

What's the mathemagic / query voodoo that gets me exclusive use of each side?

Comment: How come we get that `AcceptedOffer` with `id = 10` was **succeeded**, when `AcceptedOffer` with `id = 11` **failed**? It seems that you want `AcceptedOfferId` *property* (insetead of `ProductId`) within `Delivery` class (whether or not offer has been delivered)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thank you, So a user ordered 2 Drinks, we attempted to deliver those drinks via bleeding edge drone technology but one drone got shot down -> one made it and one didn't - the API only tells us which products were delivered within the context of a users order number

Comment: *which offer* (with `id = 11` or `id = 10`) failed to be delivered? Now we can't resolve the ambiguity: `Drink | 10 | Success; Drink | 11 | Failure` and `Drink | 11 | Success; Drink | 10 | Failure`.

Comment: It doesn't matter because they are both the same product

Comment: I simply need to update the AcceptedOffers.DeliveryStatus to reflect how many; I understand the ambiguity from a single unit level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you can try *Linq* `SelectMany` and `Zip` in order to implement *zipping* (i.e. joining `N`th offer with `N`th delivery):

```
Accepted Offer            ->  Delivery
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
{ Id = 10, ProductId = 1} -> { Id = 101, ProductId = 1, Status = "Success" } 
{ Id = 11, ProductId = 1} -> { Id = 102, ProductId = 1, Status = "Failure" }
 ...
 N-th offer               -> N-th delivery
```

**Code:**

```
   var result = products // for each product                              
     .SelectMany(prod => deliveries             
         // we get corresponding deliveries
        .Where(del => del.ProductId = prod.Id)  
         // which we mechanically zip with filtered accepted offeres
        .Zip(accepted.Where(acc => acc.ProductId = prod.Id), 
           (del, acc) => new {
             d  = del.Status,
             p  = prod.Id,   
             ao = acc.Id,
         }));
```

Comment: I saw you working thru that, fantastic!  == for compares in the wheres ;) Thank you so much :D